How to AssertEquals 2 object arrays (both with an array field)
I am trying to assert that 2 arrays of a UserDto object are equal to one another in a unit test that I am implementing. See below my UserDto class and the 2 UserDto instances I am trying to compare
UserDto class:
public record UserDto(
    @NotBlank Long id,
    @NotBlank String name,
    @NotBlank String lastname,
    @NotBlank String email,
    @NotBlank String[] roles) {
}

Instances of UserDto
 UserDto basicUserDto = new UserDto(
            2L,
            "donquixote",
            "doflamingo",
            "doffy@acme.com",
            new String[]{"ROLE_USER"}
        );


UserDto accountantUserDto = new UserDto(
            3L,
            "monkey",
            "d-luffy",
            "luffy@acme.com",
            new String[]{"ROLE_ACCOUNTANT"}
        );

Below I have my expected and actual objects, and my assertArrayEquals() call:
    UserDto[] expectedDtoArray = new UserDto[]{basicUserDto, accountantUserDto};
    UserDto[] actualDtoArray = userHelper.buildUserDtoArray(List.of(basicUser, accountantUser));
    assertArrayEquals(expectedDtoArray, actualDtoArray);

when I run this test, I get the following response:
array contents differ at index [0], expected: <UserDto[id=2, name=donquixote, lastname=doflamingo, email=doffy@acme.com, roles=[Ljava.lang.String;@79d06bbd]> but was: <UserDto[id=2, name=donquixote, lastname=doflamingo, email=doffy@acme.com, roles=[Ljava.lang.String;@2caa5d7c]>

Expected :UserDto[id=2, name=donquixote, lastname=doflamingo, email=doffy@acme.com, roles=[Ljava.lang.String;@79d06bbd]

Actual   :UserDto[id=2, name=donquixote, lastname=doflamingo, email=doffy@acme.com, roles=[Ljava.lang.String;@2caa5d7c]

Is there a way to assert that 2 array of objects with an array field are equal without having to manually implement separate method that will compare the 2 array fields?
I tried converting both arrays to a String object using the toString() method, which did not work. I also tried using ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString() method which also did not work.

Please edit your question to have appropriate formatting - use the preview to check that the post looks right before submitting it. (I'd be surprised if you really wanted it to look like this.)

Additionally, please show the code for UserDto. We have no idea whether it overrides equals for example.

@JonSkeet thanks for the feedback (this is my first question). I've fixed the formatting and added the code for UserDto

I didn't override equals. Silly mistake, thanks your hint solved the problem for me.

If you think this question can help others, then consider answering your own question, otherwise, I think you should delete the question since, by your own admission, it was a silly mistake on your part.

I did not implement the equals method in my UserDto class.
See below equals method implementation. Since the id field is a unique field, if the UserDto objects have the same id field, both objects will be considered equal.
equals() implementation below:
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        UserDto dto = (UserDto)o;
        if (this.id.equals(dto.id)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

